# Powershell Copy-item error

Tags: powershell, copy, copy-item

I want to copy a list of file in a directory using powershell :

```
$Dest="C:\temp"
$Fiches = ls -File '\\srv\share$\fiche*.pdf' #Fiches contains the list of all fiche*.pdf

foreach($Fiche in $Fiches){
   Copy-Item $Fiche $Dest #send me an error : "syntaxe incorrect" with this line underlined
}
```

Any idea ? (My file name contans spaces)

Comment: paste the exact error

Comment: Copy-Item : The file name syntax or directory is incorrect.
Au caractère \\SRV\share\myscript.ps1:6 : 5
+     Copy-Item $Fiche $Dest
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Comment: My share contain a  $. It should be the problem.
\\srv\data$\

Comment: use the  `-LiteralPath` parameter

Comment: Same result : ```Copy-Item -LiteralPath $Fiche $Dest```

Answer (score 0):

Was an accent problem in the Dest path, sorry for this bad question

Answer (score -1):

Specify `.FullName` as the property of `$Fiche` when using `Copy-Item` to get the full path :

```
$Dest="C:\temp"
$Fiches = Get-ChildItem -File '\\srv\share$\fiche*.pdf' #Fiches contains the list of all fiche*.pdf

foreach($Fiche in $Fiches){
   Copy-Item $Fiche.FullName -Destination $Dest
}
```

Comment: My file name contans spaces